# Armadillo ifft dimension

Tags: signal-processing

Does Armadillo [ifft](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#fft) support "dim" as [Octave/Matlab](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Signal-Processing.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Armadillo documentation reads "If given a matrix, the transform is done on each column vector of the matrix".  So, no, it does not support `dim`, but you can treat Armadillo's `ifft()` method as Octave/MATLAB's with `dim = 1` (columns).

If you instead want to perform `ifft()` with rows, then you can just transpose your input matrix...

```
mat X; // This is the matrix you want to call ifft() on.
// The second transpose is optional, but it will get the Y matrix to have 
// the same dimension as the X matrix.
mat Y = ifft(X.t()).t();
```